# CSS @Media for iphone and other devices?

Tags: iphone, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to get my responsive website to "respond" when on iphone or ipad for example... my css file is linked here - http://uximag.com/styles.css

All the responsive style is at the bottom of the stylesheet. it works fine while on a desktop but when I go to an iPhone it doesn't work?

Please let me know, I've tried a few methods and cant seem to figure it out.

Comment: To target Iphone you should have a max-width of 320px

Answer (score 0):

JimmyRare's comment is a good one. Set your max width to be smaller (640px for iPhone5) and it should apply to your iDevices and your browser when it's shrunk down.

Another option is setting up the code in your HTML document, which isn't ideal in that it combines your HTML writeup with your styling, but it has the added benefit of letting you target the width of the screen's resolution and not the browser width:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width: 640px)" href="640.css" />
```

Comment: It seems to work now, except when I add the aspect ratio now it still doesn't translate? everything is really small....

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? Do you mean that setting both the height and the width leads to strange behavior?